# SpringMVC, MySQL dynamic query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

How I can make one dynamic query in Spring MVC with all my all my parameters from URL?
For exemple:`/example?parameter1=test&parameter2=apple;fruit&parameter3=Park`

For that link I want to have a query like that: `SELECT * FROM news WHERE parameter1 = test AND parameter2 = apple AND fruits AND parameter3 = Park`

In in the same time if I have a URL like that `/example?parameter1=test&parameter2=apple`

I don't want to create a new query in some one like `SELECT * FROM news WHERE parameter1 = test AND parameter2 = apple;`

More exactly, how can I create a dynamic query how change automatic in function of parameters from URL?

Answer (score 1):

Its not good idea to pass dynamic data to query which will surely cause you SQL injection attacks.

You can use BeanPropRowMapper (http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) and prepared statement kind of approach (Named parameters http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-jdbc-template-named-params.jsp) in Spring JDBC to achieve similar but typed query. ( Your Java Bean getter and setter are automatically called, query is updated from that)

Don't write dynamic query ( keep it strict typed)

Answer (score 0):

Check this if you can use it..

```
  public StringBuilder prepareQuery(String tblName, String url)
   {
      StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("Select * from " + tblName + "   Where ");

    String[] params = url.split("&");

    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++ )
    {
        String str = params[i];
        System.out.println(str.contains(";"));
        if (i == 0)
        {

            query.append(str.replaceAll(";", " AND "));
        }
        else
        {
            query.append(" AND " + str.replaceAll(";", " AND "));

        }
    }
    return query;
}
```